# Need help on a select to gather data from Access database

Tags: sql, ms-access

inside a PowerShell script I need to gather data from an Access database. This is mainly a log of my terminal server: each time someone logs on or off, a script adds a line to my database with the below information (in fact many more but i keep it easy :) ).

Here are the reccord of the database :

table log_table

```
date_ac              Dept                          User_ac         Typeaccess
1/1/2014             dept1                         user1           logon
1/1/2014             dept3                         user2           logon
1/1/2014             dept3                         user2           logoff
1/1/2014             dept1                         user1           logoff
1/1/2014             dept1                         user1           logon
1/1/2014             dept1                         user1           logoff
2/1/2014             dept1                         user1           logon
```

I want to group this by departement, depending on the date requested, and showing the number of DIFFERENT people that logged on (so typeaccess logon only, not logoff) during that time line BASED on a day (so if a user log day one, it counts for one, if he logs day two, that counts for one too but if you log 20 times day one that will still counts just for one).

So in my exemple the result must be for a request 1/1/2014 -> 2/1/2014:

- dept1: 2 (user1 logged otwice the 1/1 but it counts only for one and once the 2/1 so the total is 2 as it is day based)
- dept3: 1

My problem is that I can't get rid of the "uniqueness" of the user name, as if a user logon twice or more per day that must count in my total as one.

Currently I tried this:

```
SELECT log_table.dept, Count(log_table.user_ac) 
AS CountOfuser_ac 
FROM log_table 
WHERE (((log_table.[typeaccess])='LOGON') AND
  ((log_table.[date_ac]) Between #1/1/2014# And #2/1/2014#))
GROUP BY log_table.dept
```

That work BUT it does count the user each time he logs on.

As request here is the output i would like :

```
Dept              Total nbr user
dept1             2
dept3             1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the desired output you'd like to obtain from the sample data you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gather the unique users per department and day in a subquery where you group by `dept`, `date_ac` and `user_ac`, then group that subquery by department to get the numbers you want:

```
SELECT t1.[dept], Count(t1.[user_ac]) AS [Unique Logins]
FROM (
  SELECT [date_ac], [dept], [user_ac]
  FROM [log_table]
  WHERE [typeaccess] = 'LOGON' AND
    [date_ac] BETWEEN #1/1/2014# AND #2/1/2014#
  GROUP BY [dept], [date_ac], [user_ac]
) t1
GROUP BY t1.[dept]
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for taking time to answer ! I tried that request but it seems to not work :( i assume at the end it is a AS t1 but still he doesn't give me any output (i tried directly the query in access not from my script). It ask me enter paramater value typeaccess: ) then when i clik ok no output. Thanks !

Comment: @StephaneRiviere Put the identifiers in square brackets (see updated answer). Using the keyword AS for defining the subquery alias name is optional. Both `SELECT ... FROM (...) t1 ...` and `SELECT ... FROM (...) AS t1 ...` should work. I tested with Access 2013.

Comment: Added what i type in my question still same message

Comment: Never mind was a typo that just WORKS !!! Very impressed thank you very very much ! Have a nice day !